# Maybe someone get this Dataflow BigQuery name value error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Creating new job from template in Dataflow and than it comes to writing BigQuery table dataset ID I get this error:

[image]

> Error: value must be of the form ".+:.+..+"

Try to google it, but didn't find anything, maybe it some new rule, because before I create the same way, but never get this error.

Maybe someone know what does it mean?

Comment: Can you try this`crmi-sandbox-d4b2c17a:paveldemo.mtable001`, (my-project:dataset.table)? Let me know if this helps you or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As proposed by @kiranMathew in the above comment, you have to propose the table with following convention :

```
project:dataset.table
```

The error message indicates this and you can't add special characters like `+` .

Comment: For more context, the error message is giving a pattern in regular expression syntax (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In particular, `.` means "any character", `+` means "at least one occurrence", and `\.` means a literal period.